# How to check multiple conditions for selected cases and then categorize to several levels more efficient way?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with vital signs measurements which is organized in long format, so one column with the name of test in rows (SYSBP, DIABP etc) and one column with corresponding data values. It looks like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| SYSBP | 120 |
| SYSBP | 118 |
| SYSBP | 116 |
| DIABP | 80 |
| DIABP | 75 |
| DIABP | 81 |

My aim is to check whether values in Column B are within pre-defined reference range for each parameter (SYSBP, DIABP) and depending on the result further categorize it to one of three levels - LOW, NORMAL, HIGH and write it to another column (say, Column C).

The problem  I faced with is how to apply different conditions simultaneously to SYSBP, DIABP, i.e. without splitting the dataset to multiple ones.

My only solution I`ve managed to implement is to split dataframe (say d1 in example below) by filtering on Column A to get separate dataframes with SYSBP data and DIABP data and then to combine the results into whole dataframe.

```
sysbp <- d1 |> filter(VSTESTCD == 'SYSBP')
diabp <- d1 |> filter(VSTESTCD == 'DIABP')

sysbp <- sysbp |> 
  mutate(VSNRIND = case_when(
  VSSTRESN < 110 ~ 'LOW',
  VSSTRESN > 115 ~ 'HIGH',
  TRUE ~ 'NORMAL'
  ))
unique(sysbp$VSNRIND)

diabp <- diabp |> 
  mutate(VSNRIND = case_when(
    VSSTRESN < 65 ~ 'LOW',
    VSSTRESN > 75 ~ 'HIGH',
    TRUE ~ 'NORMAL'
  ))
unique(diabp$VSNRIND)

artpressure <- rbind(sysbp, diabp)
```

That works fine, but it is OK if you have a few parameters to check. My question is may be a more efficient way how to deal with that?

For example, for laboratory data with 20-30 variables reference ranges depend on sex (male/female) as well, so I have to check this variable to assign proper range. So I dont want to split dataframe into 20 (or even more) pieces and then combine them together.

I prefer to use tidyverse package but any other solutions are fine.

Comment: Do you need to take patient age into consideration? The normal ranges for a baby differ greatly from an adult. Also, patient class: Is the patient diabetic, pregnant, or a smoker?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a join.  Create a data frame containing your keys and cut off values and then use an inequality join to merge the data.  You need to ensure that your key data frame is in ascending order and take the first match. You can add extra keys to account for gender etc.

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- tribble(
  ~Column_A,    ~Column_B,
"SYSBP",    120,
"SYSBP",    118,
"SYSBP",    116,
"DIABP",    80,
"DIABP",    75,
"DIABP",    81)

key_dat <- tribble(
  ~Column_A, ~Value, ~VSNRIND,
  "SYSBP", 110, "Low",
  "SYSBP", 116, "Normal",
  "SYSBP", Inf, "High",
  "DIABP", 65, "Low",
  "DIABP", 76, "Normal",
  "DIABP", Inf, "High")

dat %>%
  left_join(key_dat, join_by(Column_A, Column_B < Value), multiple = "first") %>%
  select(-Value)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Column_A Column_B VSNRIND
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>  
1 SYSBP         120 High   
2 SYSBP         118 High   
3 SYSBP         116 High   
4 DIABP          80 High   
5 DIABP          75 Normal 
6 DIABP          81 High
```

Alternatively, you could use `case_match()`/`case_when()` but this approach will become more complex as the number of conditions grows.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(VSNRIND = case_match(
    Column_A,
    "SYSBP" ~ case_when(Column_B < 110 ~ 'Low',
                        Column_B > 115 ~ 'High',
                        TRUE ~ 'Normal'),
    "DIABP" ~ case_when(Column_B < 65 ~ 'Low',
                        Column_B > 75 ~ 'High',
                        TRUE ~ 'Normal')
  ))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Column_A Column_B VSNRIND
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>  
1 SYSBP         120 High   
2 SYSBP         118 High   
3 SYSBP         116 High   
4 DIABP          80 High   
5 DIABP          75 Normal 
6 DIABP          81 High
```

Comment: Hello, @lotus, thanks for reply. Sorry, but I couldnt catch your idea.

Comment: My example is only for represet how my data is organized.  I have more than 10 thousands rows in my dataset for DIABP, SYSBP and other parameters.

Comment: Take a second look at the example key data frame - it's just about translating your `case_when()` conditions into the appropriate format.  If you have many conditions to define, then it's easier to use Excel or the like to create a data frame and use a join than it is to specify all the conditions in a script in your IDE to use with `case_when()`. Anyway, see edit for an alternative.

Comment: Hello, @lotus. I've understood the code you provided :) Very helpful and elegant solution in both variants that fit my tasks